# MySQL update: lock wait timeout. However, The lock bears on the table size

Tags: mysql, database

I encounter a MySQL transaction lock problem, but I don't know why.

Here's the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE test.tmp
(
 id INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 c2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
 c3 INT         NOT NULL,
 c4 INT         NOT NULL
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE INDEX tmp_c2_index ON tmp (c2);
```

Table Data:

[image]

trx1:

```
BEGIN ;
UPDATE test.tmp SET c3=100 WHERE c2='b';----（1)
```

trx2:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE test.tmp SET c3=50 WHERE c2='a';----（2)
```

When execute trx2 sql(2), if reduce some records with c2='a'(eg. delete 3 records with c2='a') then no lock wait; if add more records with c2='a' then lock wait happens. It's so weird!

When lock wait happens, I query for the lock info.

```
select * from information_schema.innodb_locks;
```

[image]

Can anyone help me, thx.

Comment: Does column c2 have an index?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes! CREATE INDEX tmp_c2_index ON tmp (c2);